# Update array object object value using spread operator

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to update a value from an array object and object. my sample code is below. Not getting the result as I expected. It would be nice if someone can help?

```
    let array = [
        {   
            id:"01",
            "name": {
                "value": "jaison",
                "error": null
            },
            "email": {
                "value": "jaison@yopmail.com",
                "error": null
            }
        },
        {
            id:"02",
            "name": {
                "value": "jaison 1",
                "error": null
            },
            "email": {
                "value": "jaison1@yopmail.com",
                "error": null
            }
        }
    ];

    this.state{
        data:array
    }

    //This two data getting a from a form
    const key = "02";
    const editedData = {name:"updated jaison 1", email:"updatedjaison1@yopmail.com"}

    const newData = [...this.state.data];

    const index = newData.findIndex(item => key === item.id);

    let item = newData[index];

    //Working as expcted 
    console.log('1', item);

    Object.keys(editedData).forEach(function (key) {
      item[key] = editedData[key];
    });

    //Working as expcted 
    console.log('2', item);

    this.setState({ data: [...this.state.data, item]}, () => {
        //Not Working as expcted 
        console.log(this.state.data);
    });

    Expected result
   let array = [
    {   
        id:"01",
        "name": {
            "value": "jaison",
            "error": null
        },
        "email": {
            "value": "jaison@yopmail.com",
            "error": null
        }
    },
    {
        id:"02",
        "name": {
            "value": "updated jaison 1",
            "error": null
        },
        "email": {
            "value": "updatedjaison1@yopmail.com",
            "error": null
        }
    }
];
```

Comment: You're getting the index of the item you need to replace, but you're not overwriting the data declared in `editedData` which is unused.

Comment: You can directly assign value because you have index right 
this.state.data[2].name.value = "updated jaison 1"; this.state.data[2].email.value ="updatedjaison1@yopmail.com" if you don't know the index that could be different case. hope it works

Comment: Object.keys(editedData).forEach(function (key) {
      item[key] = editedData[key];
    }); this is the code I am trying to overwrite or update the data because I can not blindly overnight the data due to a different format

Comment: @adiga Answer working for me, any more shortest answers are welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you update `item[key]` inside the `forEach`, it just updates `name` and `email` with a string values. Also, it mutates the `state`

Instead, you could loop throguh `editedData` object update the clone of that specific index. Use the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to keep `error` and other properties as it is and update only the `value` property. Then update the index of the cloned `data` array and call `setState` like this:

```
const key = "02",
      editedData = { name: "updated jaison 2", email: "updatedjaison2@yopmail.com" },
      data = [...this.state.data],
      index = data.findIndex(item => key === item.id),
      updatedData = { ...data[index] };

// loop through and update only the keys you need 
for(const key in editedData) {
  updatedData[key] = { ...updatedData[key], value: editedData[key] }
}

data[index] = updatedData;

this.setState({ data })
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, You are almost there. But 2 things missing.
after updated the array disappeared the properties other than the edited one form the first level of the object. Also, I can not give error: null manually for the inner object becouse there is probability to have some more properties there, so can we use a spread operator(...restProps)?

Comment: @Jaison updated the answer. Please try it and let me know

Comment: Thanks, dear, it's working perfectly what I am looking for, Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of finding the index and using a `forEach` to loop over the array, I'd do something like:

```
const updatedArray = newData.map(item => {
   // if editedData has a key attribute:
   if (item.id === editedData.key) {
       return editedData; //you'd need to add a key attribute to the data
   } else {
       return item;
   }
});
this.setState({data: updatedArray});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, request you to have a detailed understanding of my question and expected data structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `map`:

```
   let array = [
        {   
            id:"01",
            "name": {
                "value": "jaison",
                "error": null
            },
            "email": {
                "value": "jaison@yopmail.com",
                "error": null
            }
        },
        {
            id:"02",
            "name": {
                "value": "jaison 1",
                "error": null
            },
            "email": {
                "value": "jaison1@yopmail.com",
                "error": null
            }
        }
    ];

    const key = "02";

    const updated = array.map(item => {
        if (item.id === key) {
            return {id: key, name:"updated jaison 1", email:"updatedjaison1@yopmail.com"}
        }
        return item;
    });

setState({data: updated});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, request you to have a detailed understanding of my question and expected data structure.